# Google Maps comportamento em dispositivos móveis

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Oi

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto no qual uma página será apenas o mapa. Preciso de algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando ele for em dispositivos móveis, não quero que dê a opção de rolar com dois dedos. Quero que o usuário navegue normalmente, com se tivesse aberto o google maps no celular. Estou a horas pesquisando e tudo o que encontrei foi documentos do Google pelo comportamento "gestureHandling". A opção seria a "greedy". Mais isso geral outro problema. Quando configuro essa opção, faz a navegação que quero, mas deixa o mapa muito pobre de informações como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo. Alguém já passou por algum problema assim?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao todo: Preciso que o mapa mostre as informações como na primeira imagem, mas que possa rolar em celular sem utilizar os dois dedos.

Comment: Você consegue identificar se o cara tá logado no celular ou em um pc.. uma saída é bloquear o _zoom_ qdo tiver no _mobile_ (limitar o _min_ e o _max_ para o q abre)

Comment: Sim, mas quero que o cliente tenha total liberdade sobre o mapa...